# Calling get_host_byid from libnmap returns "None" instead of a host object

Tags: python, nmap

Using the python libnmap module, I have this python code:

```
def DiffScan(Old, New):
        Added = Old.diff(New).added()
        for i in Added:
            anIP = i.split('::')[1]
            print "IP for lookup is " + anIP + " of " + str(type(anIP))
            anewhost = New.get_host_byid(anIP)
            pprint.pprint(anewhost)
```

When I call this function, I get the output:

```
 IP for lookup is X.X.X.X of <type 'str'>
 None
 IP for lookup is Y.Y.Y.Y of <type 'str'>
 None
```

My expectation is that instead of "none", I would get something like :

```
IP for lookup is Z.Z.Z.Z of <type 'str'>
NmapHost: [Z.Z.Z.Z () - up]
```

I am unsure why the call to `.get_host_byid()` is returning None and not an `NMapHost` object. Perhaps there is something wrong with my `anIP` string, but I cannot find the error.

Comment: I have done some more experimentation using .get_host_byid() off a saved libnmap.objects.report object.  I am calling the function with literal IP addresses that I know are in the report.  Some of the time I get back an NmapHost object and sometimes I get back "None".  Based on the data I use I should get an NMapHost object each time.  The scan the report is based on is over 20mb.  Could there be an issue with a variable that is too large?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: I called the diff function incorrectly.

Longer Answer

There is nothing wrong with the libnmap diff function.  The original code in the question above has a logic error and is calling the diff function incorrectly.  It was returning "None" as the set of hosts queried did not contain the requested host, which is expected behaviour.  The correct call should be:

```
Added = New.diff(Old).added()
```

In other words, swapping the positions of the two variables in the function call.  Then the call to

```
New.get_host_byid(anIP)
```

will then work correctly.  Extending this to the other diff functions, the code for removed hosts should be:

```
Removed = New.diff(Old).removed()
```

and then use

```
Old.get_host_byid(anIP)
```

The code for changed hosts should be

```
Changed = New.diff(Old).changed()
```

and then use

```
New.get_host_byid(anIP)
```

The code for unchanged hosts should be

```
Unchanged = New.diff(Old).unchanged()
```

and then use

```
New.get_host_byid(anIP)
```